# Inverse of linear combination of trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse

I have an equation of the form:

$$\tan(y)=\alpha_1\cos(x)+\alpha_2\sin(x)$$

where $x$ and $y$ are in $(0,2\pi)$ and the coefficients are real numbers.

Implicitly this defines $y$ as a function of $X$, say $y = f(x)$.

Is there a clever expression for $x = f^{-1}(y)$, or do we need to find it numerically (i.e. using an iterative root finder)?

Comment: Sorry, I did not make myself clear.  Let me just edit to say what I think you mean, and you can review.

Comment: yes, this was what I meant. I expect there to be multiple definitions for $f^{-1}(y)$ (because of the shape of the function, i.e. it's not everywhere monotone), but I wonder if it is possible, based on $y,r,\phi$ to decide which of the candidate inverse function is the correct one!

Comment: Indeed the right hand side is not a one-one (injective) function of $x$, so there is no hope of giving an inverse function without further restrictions on the domain and range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\alpha_1\cos(x)+\alpha_2\sin(x) =\Re(e^{ix}\overline{(a_1+ia_2)}).$$ Now let $r$ be the module of $a_1+ia_2$ and $\phi$ its principal argument. You can easily check that $$\alpha_1\cos(x)+\alpha_2\sin(x) =\Re(e^{ix}\overline{(a_1+ia_2)}) = r\cos(x-\phi).$$ Hence the inversion of the equality $$\tan(y) = r\cos(x-\phi)$$ gives $$x =\phi+\arccos{\left(\frac{\tan(y)}{r}\right)}.$$

Comment: Super, thank you sire!

Comment: I have a small problem, for some cases (say x=4.895129, $\alpha_1=.21$ and $\alpha_2=.85$) the formula works up to $\tan(y)=r\cos(x−\phi)$ ($\phi=1.328588$ and $r=0.875557$) but the last formula (after the "gives") doesn't. Would you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You know that $\cos(x) = y$ has more than one solution. I wrote the standard $\arccos(y)$ but there is also the opposite and you can add $2k\pi$ as well.

Comment: So, how do you choose among (say for $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$) 3 possible inverses? Can you choose on the basis of the value of $y$ or $r$ or $\phi$?